# Why does the Chinese immigration ask for the Hong Kong landing slip when applying for the Shenzhen SEZ Tourism Visa when entering Shenzhen?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas, hong-kong, shenzhen

Why does the Chinese immigration ask for the Hong Kong landing slip when applying for the 5-day visa ("[Shenzhen Special Economic Zone Tourism Visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_China&oldid=867954431#Special_Economic_Zone_visa_on_arrival)") when entering Shenzhen through one of the ports that deliver such visa, and can one still obtain the the 5-day visa if one doesn't have the Hong Kong landing slip anymore? I am a French citizen if that matters.

---

Hong Kong landing slip:

[image]

Quoting someone from https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294217-i1496-k11283718-Landing_Slips_yes_i_know_i_can_t_have_a_stamp-Hong_Kong.html ([mirror](http://archive.ph/wWNkO)):

> One circumstance under which you may have to obtain a replacement if the landing slip is lost would be if you wish to apply for a China visa whilst in HK.
>
> The Immigration Dept indicates that passports may still be stamped under “exceptional circumstances” but that probably means failure of the computer system.

Comment: I don't think it would matter much.

Comment: they might ask for the slip because they want to verify how long have you been in HK before applying for such a visa in order to help them with the assessment of your application. that being said - I was never asked for this slip.. and BTW - the quoted remark speaks of `whilst in HK` and not the SZ VOA

Answer (score 4):

This is not common criteria - this is part of a simple spot check exercise to find people applying from VISA that did not arrive at the border gate by proper transport. For a period of about 6 months a few years ago I had move from a permanent residency permit in China to monthly tourist visa until my company was setup and I could once again get a permanent residency visa in China, and during that period I made frequent visa runs from HK to SZ and I also noticed this from time to time even at the land border between HK and SZ so I asked them and they explained it as "spot checks randomly selected for further scrutiny".

Comment: Thanks, interesting, do you know what happen if one cannot provide the Hong Kong landing slip if asked for it?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I have never heard of anyone having any issues with that, that challenge is a HK departure procedure challenge if anything not fore the inbound country to worry about, I think they simply use it as a selection criteria nothing else