# Can one just keep a picture of the Hong Kong landing slip, or does one have to keep the paper version of it?

Tags: paperwork, hong-kong

Can one just keep a picture/scan of the Hong Kong landing slip, or does one have to keep the paper version of it?

---

Hong Kong landing slip:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need to keep the landing slip at all**, it's for your own reference only.  If you use the [automated gates](https://www.businesstraveller.com/business-travel/2018/09/20/hong-kong-airport-now-has-facial-recognition-technology-at-its-security-gates/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190103041433/https://www.businesstraveller.com/business-travel/2018/09/20/hong-kong-airport-now-has-facial-recognition-technology-at-its-security-gates/)) at the airport, you'll never even talk to a human when leaving, much less need to show it to anyone.

The one catch you already pointed out in [your other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129112/why-does-the-chinese-immigration-ask-for-the-hong-kong-landing-slip-when-applyin): you may need to show the slip if applying for mainland China visas in Hong Kong.  (And no, I don't know if PRC authorities would accept a photo.)

See also: 
[How can I leave Hong Kong when I've lost my landing slip (Departure card)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87914/how-can-i-leave-hong-kong-when-ive-lost-my-landing-slip-departure-card)